# How do I do a simple Exec activity in TFS Build 2010

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

TFS Build 2010 is completely different from 2008. There is no "Exec" task - I'm looking for a 2010 equivalent "activity". Is there a way to perform a basic command line execution in TFS Build 2010?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the "InvokeProcess" activity in your team build process.  Take a look at Chapter 21 of the following book I co-authored:

- [Professional Application Lifecycle Management with Visual Studio 2010](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-Application-Lifecycle-Management-with-Visual-Studio-2010.productCd-0470484268.html)

Chapter 21 is available as a free download from the link above - from about page 500 you should find the bit you need.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Wow - it was as simple as opening up the "Toolbar" in Visual Studio. I hate "drag and drop development" and always keep that thing closed. For workflows (which I've never created/modified), I can see the value. For some reason, none of the blog posts I've found have explicitly pointed out dragging items from the tool bar. Thanks!

Comment: Cool - glad it helped.  I actually find that I sometimes edit workflows a fair bit in a straight text editor which I why I included the XAML samples in the book (and also because it de-mysifies what you are doing).  But the drag/drop from the toolbar sure makes the stuff much more discoverable (which you can then edit in notepad later :-) )

I'll be sure to blog about some of this stuff as well now that the product is released.  It was changing so much during the beta's that it wasn't really worth it back then.